# Как в django сделать загрузку нескольких файлов из одной формы

Tags: python, django

Доброго времени суток, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать, что б на одной странице, были 2 кнопки загрузки файлов (при создании элемента, мне нужно подгружать 2 разных списка из 2-ух разных файлов). Моя версия в упор не видит второго файла, а если загружаешь первый то кнопка добавления второго файла вообще исчезает.

views.py:

```
def add_company_view(request):
cur_user = request.user.username
if request.method == 'POST':
    add_company = AddCompanyForm(request.POST)
    add_keys = AddKeysForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    add_tank_id = AddIdTankForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if add_company.is_valid():
        new_company = add_company.save()
        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Компания успешно зарегистрирована.')
        try:
            key_doc = request.FILES['key_file'].read().decode().split()
            key_counter = 0
            for key in key_doc:
                if len(key) == 16 and all(c in string.hexdigits for c in key):
                    try:
                        KeyStore.objects.get(keys=key)
                        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Ключ ' + key + ' уже существует в БД.')
                    except KeyStore.DoesNotExist:
                        new_key = KeyStore(keys=key, company=new_company)
                        new_key.save()
                        key_counter += 1
                else:
                    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Ключ ' + key + ' некорректен.')
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO,
                                 'Добавлено ' + str(key_counter) + ' ключей из ' + str(len(key_doc)) + '.')
            tank_id_doc = request.FILES['id_tank_file'].read().decode().split()
            tank_id_counter = 0
            for tank_id in tank_id_doc:
                try:
                    IdTank.objects.get(tank_id=tank_id)
                    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Номер датчика ' + tank_id + 'уже существует')
                except IdTank.DoesNotExist:
                    new_tank_id = IdTank(tank_id=tank_id, company=new_company)
                    new_tank_id.save()
                    tank_id_counter += 1
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Добавленно ' + str(tank_id_counter) + 'номеров датчиков из ' + str(len(tank_id_doc) + '.'))

        except MultiValueDictKeyError:
            add_keys = AddKeysForm()
            add_tank_id = AddIdTankForm()
else:
    add_company = AddCompanyForm()
    add_keys = AddKeysForm()
    add_tank_id = AddIdTankForm()
return render(request, 'local_admin/add_company.html', {'cur_user': cur_user, 'add_company': add_company, 'add_keys': add_keys, 'add_tank_id': add_tank_id})
```

forms.py:

```
class AddCompanyForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Company
    fields = {'name', 'comment'}
    widgets = {'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Название',
                                              'required': 'True', 'maxlength': 100}),
               'comment': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Комментарий'})}

class AddKeysForm(forms.Form):
key_file = forms.FileField(label='', required=False)

class AddIdTankForm(forms.Form):
id_tank_file = forms.FileField(label='', required=False)
```

models.py:

```
class KeyStore(models.Model):
keys = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
owned = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.keys

class IdTank(models.Model):
tank_id = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
owned = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.tank_id
```

html:

```
        <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default panel-my">
        <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-my"><h4>Добавить компанию</h4></div>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
                {{ add_company.name }}
                {{ add_company.comment }}
                <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <span class="btn btn-file">
                    <i class="icon-plus"> </i><span>Файл ключей</span>
                        {{ add_keys }}
                </span>
                <span class="btn btn-file">
                    <i class="icon-plus"> </i><span>Файл номеров датчиков</span>
                        {{ add_tank_id }}

                </span>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
                        <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-file" type="submit">Добавить</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Мне кажется проблема где-то в яваскрипте - изчезать не должно!

Comment: покажи кусок хтмл каким он доходит до браузера...

Comment: request.POST он же общий или это сразу три страницы?